# git config --global insteadOf for a project, not global

Tags: git, config

I created a `.gitconfig` file using the command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

However, this will replace all `git:// URLs WITH https://` ones, for all projects on my computer.

I want this functionality, for a specific project. 
Is it possible to configure a replace for `git:// URLs for https:// URLs` for a certain project/not global?

This project is shared, and I don't want everyone to go through the trouble of running the command locally.

Comment: try git config --system once

Comment: config --system is system wide, won't help in this case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Edit .gitconfig file and just remove the [url] section.
2. Cd into the project in which you want this `instead` to work.
3. Run `git config url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Explaination:

`git config --global` is your user-wide setting, i.e it is applied to all projects in that users home dir. The config file is `.gitconfig` and it resides in user's homedir

`git config` is repository specific configuration. If adds an entry in your $GIT_DIR/config file. So it is specific to only that directory

Hope it helps!

Happy gitting!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
git config --local
```

Out of your (git) project source directory to do project / repository specific configurations.

---

The own git documentation often helps, e.g.

```
git config //List of Commands & Options
git help config //the complete documentation about the config command
```