# git config insteadOf doesn't work without --global for local repository

Tags: git

This question has been asked before at [git config --global insteadOf for a project, not global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974697/git-config-global-insteadof-for-a-project-not-global) but the accepted solution doesn't work for me.

```sh
# Random directory

$ pwd
$ /tmp/nwani_1585850170


# Now, a local repo

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/nwani_1585850170/.git/


# Pretty modern git (as of April, 2020)

$ git --version
git version 2.21.1


# Don't have any existing config

$ git config --list | grep url


# Let's configure the insteadOf thingy for the local repo:

$ git config url."ssh://".insteadOf "https://"


# Verify that it indeed got added:

$ git config --list | grep url
url.ssh://.insteadof=https://


# Yes, it is in the local config

$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[url "ssh://"]
    insteadOf = https://


# Check if it works? Spoiler alert: It doesn't!

$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone --progress --verbose https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
13:57:17.426161 git.c:419               trace: built-in: git clone --progress --verbose https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
Cloning into 'blah'...
13:57:17.427962 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
* Couldn't find host domain.doesnt.exist in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 92.242.140.21:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
^C


# As one can see in the trace above, it runs the command git-remote-https, so it didn't honor the insteadOf thingy.


# Now let's make the config global:

$ git config --global url."ssh://".insteadOf "https://"


# Let's try it now. Spoiler alert: It works!

GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone --progress --verbose https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
13:57:48.910586 git.c:419               trace: built-in: git clone --progress --verbose https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
Cloning into 'blah'...
13:57:48.912966 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: unset GIT_DIR; ssh domain.doesnt.exist 'git-upload-pack '\''/blah'\'''
^C

# As one can see, now it is using the ssh command
```

So, my query is: How do I make git honor my local `insteadOf` config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clone` certainly doesn't obey local config — for cloning there is no local config yet, only global. Try something that uses local config; `git fetch/pull/push` for example:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah master
22:21:01.075552 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' 'https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah' 'master'
22:21:01.076706 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'domain.doesnt.exist' 'git-upload-pack '\''/blah'\'''
ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain.doesnt.exist: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If you want to use `url.insteadOf` for `clone` without setting it globally you can pass config value in the command line:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git -c url.ssh://.insteadof=https:// clone --verbose https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah
22:25:33.588762 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'clone' '--verbose' 'https://domain.doesnt.exist/blah'
Cloning into 'blah'...
22:25:33.596631 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'domain.doesnt.exist' 'git-upload-pack '\''/blah'\'''
ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain.doesnt.exist: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Okay, what's the explanation behind git clone not honoring `GIT_CONFIG` env var? Or is  it not a valid env var to be used at all with `git clone` as well?

Comment: AFAIU `GIT_CONFIG` is only valid for command `git config` and nothing else. It's mentioned in [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt--fconfig-file) but not in [`git help git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git).

Comment: While environment variable `GIT_CONFIG` does not work, `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` can be used to do the same. Ex: `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'url.git@github.com.insteadOf=https://github.com'"`. Git requires values in the environment variable to be single quoted.

Comment: @465544 Where is it documented?

Comment: This solves the problem with `git clone`.  But I think it genuinely is broken for the initial `git submodule update`.  Setting up a local insteadOf rule, has no affect on the submodule update but a global setting will.  I'm using git version 2.33.0.

Comment: I should add that once the submodule is established you need to edit the config for that submodule, not the parent repo.