# Gitlab CI authentication failing for Flutter git

Tags: flutter, git, authentication, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have several Flutter projects on a private gitlab, some of which reference the others.  When the pipeline triggers, the build fails on `flutter pub get`, because the pipeline runner fails to authenticate.  I tried adding a line to the .gitlab-ci.yml file, to `before_script`, to insert the CI_JOB_TOKEN into the repo URLs like described here [git config insteadOf doesn't work without --global for local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998250) , but the git call from `flutter pub get` appears to be ignoring that part of the global config.  See the following pipeline log.  (I've somewhat redacted it, but I don't think the specific paths and domain names matter.  It's just company/project/hash strings.  The true value of each REDACTED# field should be identical to the others of its same number.)

```
$ git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@REDACTED1.com".insteadOf https://REDACTED1.com
$ git config --list | grep url
url.https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@REDACTED1.com.insteadof=https://REDACTED1.com
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@REDACTED1.com/REDACTED2.git
$ flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror https://REDACTED1.com/REDACTED3.git /root/.pub-cache/git/cache/REDACTED4`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/root/.pub-cache/git/cache/REDACTED4'...
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
```

Any idea why the `insteadof` setting isn't taking effect?  Or any ideas how else to get Flutter to authenticate correctly?